# Partition layout with different value functions

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to implement the partition layout and have the user decide upon the value function. A radio button marks the currently used attribute which is passed on to the value function.

A working implementation by Mike Bostock (for sunburst) is here:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423

My example (see JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ee2todev/3tsogbz6/ )tries to follow that implementation but something goes wrong:
The first change on the radio button seems fine, but the second click on the radio button leads to a wrong result. To better see what goes wrong, I color coded the leaves which should stay leaves (on the right side).

The point I am missing must be in the update/transition after setting the new value function:

```
  d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
    var value;

    switch(this.value) {
      case "count":
        value = function() { return 1; }
        break;
      case "size1":
        value = function(d) { return d.values.size1; };
        break;
      case "size2":
        value = function(d) { return d.values.size2; };
        break;
    }

    d3.selectAll("g.main")
        .data(partition.value(value).nodes(root))
      .transition();
    console.log(root);  
  });
```

Any help is greatly appreciate

** update**
Even the first click on the radio button seem to produce wrong results. I must be missing something simple !?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping between the data model and the DOM elements will change everytime you call .data() on the selection. So, this means, all the attributes needs to be updated in click function

```
    t.select("rect")
        .attr("width", d.dy * kx)
        .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dx * ky; })
        .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "innerNode" : "leaf"; });

    t.select("text")
        .attr("transform", transform)
        .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.dx * ky > 12 ? 1 : 0; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
```

Notice I have set even the class for the rectangle and the text for the text element.

Here is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/4v62v9g3/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I'm not sure this is answering my question. What does the click function have to do with the function change fired by the radio buttons?

Comment: Because you are calling click(root) function in d3.select(window).onClick function. This is getting called every time you change the radio button. You can also remove this code and call the click(root) in the onChange of radio button. It will work the same way!
Hope you checked the jsfiddle link I have shared

Comment: Thanks, yes I looked at your link. Thanks for pointing out that global click event! I missed that! Probably it's better to rewrite the code to have the click event attached to the rectangles. But clicking on the radio button in the jsfiddle still doesn't produce the right visualization (the proportions of the rectangles are not reflecting the desired attributes size1 and size2.) :(

Comment: That is because of the typo. You have value='size1' for both the radio buttons :)

It should be 
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="size2">

Comment: Thanks a lot. For my wrong value setting, i should get -1 :) You helped me getting me on the right path by pointing out some crucial points, many thanks - for which I accept the answer and upvote deservedly. However, technically, solution is still not perfect: If I click on the size2 button and then on the size1 button, it reorders the rectangle such that a leaf is becoming an internal node!...

Comment: I found the missing piece: The data join in the function change() has to be: d3.selectAll("g.main")
            .data(partition.value(value).nodes(root), function (d) { return d;} );. Thanks again for leading the way !